# Is my figure correct according to the question (vectors)?

Tags: notation, vectors

**Question:**

Two concurrent forces act along the sides CA and CB of a triangle, and $\frac{P}{\cos A}=\frac{Q}{\cos B}=k$. Prove that their resultant $R=k\sin C$.

**My book's figure:**

[image]

**My figure:**

[image]

**My comments:**

We both managed to prove the given statement correctly. There are slight differences between our figures, but both are according to the question in my opinion. We both assumed an angle $\theta$, which helped us to answer the question at hand. In my book's figure, it is $\angle DCA$ while in my figure it is $\angle SCB$. My main question is that is it necessary to draw a vector $\vec{R}$ that is touching the triangle? In my book's figure, the vector $\vec{R}$ is touching the triangle at the point $D$; however, in my figure, $\vec{R}$ is not touching the triangle. So, is it necessary for $\vec{R}$ to touch the triangle?

**My question:**

1. Is it necessary for $\vec{R}$ to touch the triangle?

Comment: No. Let's assume that you have a case where the tip of $\vec R$ touches the triangle. If you multiply the forces by a constant (not 1) the problem would still be valid, and will yield the same result, but then the tip of the resultant vector does not touch the triangle. Note that your figure does not look right. Form a parallelogram with sides $\vec P$ and $\vec Q$. Then $\vec R$ is the diagonal starting from the point $C$.

Comment: @Andrei Is the fact that $\vec{R}$ does not seem to be the resultant of $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ the issue with my figure? That is, should the length of $\vec{R}$ be a bit longer?

Comment: Yes, that was my observation, something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Vector_Addition.svg

Comment: @andrei Oh, I see. I was just drawing a rough diagram, and it is not perfectly accurate. Examiners give us leeway in this matter. As long as it looks roughly "okay", it's fine. We are scored on the basis of our proof, not on the accuracy of the figure. What I wanted to know was that is the touching of $\vec{R}$ and the triangle a requirement here for some other reason?

Comment: That's fine. And as I mentioned, if it touches it's just a very unlikely coincidence.

Comment: @Andrei Understood. Thanks for your awesome response!